# how to ignore error in shell script?

Tags: scripts

Im writing a script, but it is throwing some errors when something is not found, i need ignore those error.i mean when i run the script it should display positive results if any errors should not display.

```
#!/bin/sh
boot=$(ls /bootpool | grep boot | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')
data=$(ls /datapool | grep boot | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')
echo "boot"
if [ "$boot" == "boot" ] 
then
    echo "boot"
    pass=$(grep rootpw /bootpool/boot/loader.conf| grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g' | awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }')
elif [ "$data" == "boot" ]
then
    pass=$(grep rootpw /datapool/boot/loader.conf| grep -o '".*"' | sed 's/"//g' | awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }')
fi
if [ $pass == edjos ]
then
   echo  "You are at default password. kindly change the password"
   oldpass=$(grep root /etc/master.passwd | awk 'NR==1 { print $1 }' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed 's/\$/\%/g')
   passwd
   newpass=$(grep root /etc/master.passwd | awk 'NR==1 { print $1 }' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed 's/\$/\%/g')
    if [ "$newpass" != "$oldpass" ]
     then              
          if [ "$boot" == "boot" ]
          then 
              sed -i.bak '/mfsbsd.rootpw/s/edjos//' /bootpool/boot/loader.conf
              sed -i.bak '/mfsbsd.rootpwhash/d' /bootpool/boot/loader.conf
              echo mfsbsd.rootpwhash=\"$newpass\"  >> /bootpool/boot/loader.conf
            echo "Great! password updated successfully"
          elif [ "$data" == "boot" ]
          then
             sed -i.bak '/mfsbsd.rootpw/s/edjos//' /datapool/boot/loader.conf
             sed -i.bak '/mfsbsd.rootpwhash/d' /datapool/boot/loader.conf
             echo mfsbsd.rootpwhash=\"$newpass\"  >> /datapool/boot/loader.conf
            echo "Great! password updated successfully"
         fi
    fi
    else
     echo "Great! you are having authorised password"
fi
```

Comment: Welcome, what exactly are the errors?

Comment: Your specific question is not clear but regardless of that, this script has multiple problems. I recommend installing "shellcheck" package and running it against your script, improving matters until shellcheck no longer complains.

Answer (score 6):

You can put `2>/dev/null` behind a command to suppress errors:

`ls /home/cas/thisfolderdoesntexist` -> error

`ls /home/cas/thisfolderdoesntexist 2>/dev/null` -> no output because error is suppressed.

You can also put `2>/dev/null` behind a script to run the complete script with errors suppressed:

`./script.sh 2>/dev/null`

What your doing is redirecting (`>`) errors (`2`) to `/dev/null`. Every piece of data (in this case the output of your command(s)/script) that is redirected to /dev/null will be completely ignored. See it as a trash can for data.

---

Edit:
`2>/dev/null` suppresses the output of the command, not the complete pipe. In the example that you gave, you're supressing errors from the awk command. If the error is comming from the `ls` command, do the following (this will suppress errors from the ls command):

`ls /bootpool 2>/dev/null | grep boot | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'`

If the error is comming from the grep command:

`ls /bootpool | grep boot 2>/dev/null | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'`

I think you get it now.

A good thing to remember:

`1` = stdout = normal output of a command

`2` = stderr = error output of a command

`0` = stdin = input to a command (this isn't usefull for redirecting, more for logging)

---

I also improved your script (using shellcheck, you can install it or use their online tool [link](https://www.shellcheck.net/#)):

```
#!/bin/sh
boot=$(find /bootpool/*boot* 2>/dev/null | sed "s|/.*/||")
data=$(find /datapool/*boot* 2>/dev/null | sed "s|/.*/||")
echo "boot"
if [ "$boot" = "boot" ] 
then
        echo "boot"
        pass=$(grep rootpw /bootpool/boot/loader.conf | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's|"||g' | awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }')

elif [ "$data" = "boot" ]
then
        pass=$(grep rootpw /datapool/boot/loader.conf | grep -o '".*"' | sed 's|"||g' | awk 'BEGIN { ORS = " " } { print }')

else
        echo "Couldn't find boot in bootpool nor datapool"
        exit
fi

if [ "$pass" = edjos ]
then
        echo "You are at default password. kindly change the password"
        oldpass=$(grep root /etc/master.passwd | awk 'NR==1 { print $1 }' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed 's/\$/\%/g')
        passwd
        newpass=$(grep root /etc/master.passwd | awk 'NR==1 { print $1 }' | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed 's/\$/\%/g')
        if [ "$newpass" != "$oldpass" ]
        then              
                if [ "$boot" = "boot" ]
                then 
                        sed -i.bak '/mfsbsd.rootpw/s/edjos//' /bootpool/boot/loader.conf
                        sed -i.bak '/mfsbsd.rootpwhash/d' /bootpool/boot/loader.conf
                        echo "mfsbsd.rootpwhash=\"$newpass\""  >> /bootpool/boot/loader.conf
                        echo "Great! password updated successfully"

                elif [ "$data" = "boot" ]
                then
                        sed -i.bak '/mfsbsd.rootpw/s/edjos//' /datapool/boot/loader.conf
                        sed -i.bak '/mfsbsd.rootpwhash/d' /datapool/boot/loader.conf
                        echo "mfsbsd.rootpwhash=\"$newpass\""  >> /datapool/boot/loader.conf
                        echo "Great! password updated successfully"
                fi
        fi
else
        echo "Great! you are having authorised password"
fi
```

1. You were using `==` but /bin/sh doesn't make use of that. Only `=`. When you use /bin/bash, `==` will actually become usefull. But as you don't, you need to use `=`.
2. I changed the way you set the boot and data variables. The way you did it was inefficient.
3. When both $boot and $data are empty, the script will catch it instead of letting you continue. This is handy because in your second if statement, when $oldpass and $newpass aren't equal, it depends on either $boot or $data to contain "boot". But what if they don't? That's what the `else` is for in the first if-statement.
4. Putting `""` around variables. `echo $var` -> `echo "$var"`

Comment: still im getting no file found error , ls /bootpool | grep boot | awk 'NR==1{print $1}' 2>/dev/null

Comment: @SreekanthChityala see edit of my answer

Comment: @SreekanthChityala I improved your script. See my answer

Comment: wow, so nice of you...thanks